# Eliminate LET operator and SqlFunctions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, c#-4.0

Please consider this query:

```
from r in ent.MyTable
group r by new { r.EmployeeName, r.EmployeeID } into g
let c = " (" + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal?)g.Count()) + " )"
select new
{
    EmployeeName = g.Key.EmployeeName + c ,
    EmployeeID = g.Key.EmployeeID
});
```

it works well. When I want to use this query instead, I get an error:

```
from r in ent.MyTable
group r by new { r.EmployeeName, r.EmployeeID } into g
select new
{
    EmployeeName = g.Key.EmployeeName + " (" + g.Count() + ")",
    EmployeeID = g.Key.EmployeeID
});
```

Error:

> Can not convert System.Object to System.String

How can I do that?

Comment: Add : g.Count().ToString()

Comment: @jdweng ToString isn't SQL Server function

Comment: It is linq.  But g.Count() is an integer and you need to convert it to a string.

Comment: What EF version are you on? The desired syntax perfectly works on EF6.2

Comment: One other thought: what if you selected `EmployeeName`, `EmployeeID`, and `Count` and only combined the Employee Name and count into a string later down the line.  Either in a front-end layer, or in the View if this is an MVC app?  Might be cleaner then constructing the display string in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you double transform your output?

```
from r in ent.MyTable
group r by new { r.EmployeeName, r.EmployeeID } into g
select new
{
    EmployeeName = g.Key.EmployeeName,
    Count = g.Count(),
    EmployeeID = g.Key.EmployeeID
}
into tmp
select new
{
    EmployeeName = tmp.EmployeeName + "(" + Count + ")",
    EmployeeID = tmp.EmployeeID
}
```

Comment: This is similar to what `let` operator does in OP query, which they want to avoid.

Comment: I thought query performance could be a reason for avoiding let from the original query that is why I'm performing transformation twice on the rows. If that is not the case then may be my answer is not applicable.

Comment: But, even though query in my answer seems similar, it produces completely different  SQL.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a `MyTable`, where every row (probably emploees) in the table has at least properties `EmployeeId` and `EmployeeName`.

You want to group the rows from your table into groups with equal `EmployeeId` and `EmployeeName`. From every group you want the common `EmployeeId` and the number of employees in this group in a form of the common `EmployeeName" + the number of employees.

```
var result = ent.MyTable                   // take MyTable
   .GroupBy(employee => new                // group all rows of this table into groups
   {                                       // with equal EmployeeId and EmployeeName
       Id = employee.EmployeeId,
       Name = employee.EmployeeName,
   })
   .Select(group => new                    // from every group make one object
   {                                       // with properties:
       EmployeeId = group.Key.Id,          // - the common employeeId
       EmployeeName = group.Key.Name       // - the common employeeName + the string value 
           + group.Count().ToString(),     //   of the number of elements in the group
   });
```